# knockout populate fields on change of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I'm new at Knockout JS and i am struggling with this issue, need your guidance. Everything works fine i am fable to get `ProductID` and it's `ProductOffers` VIA `Ajax` but when i second `dropdown` doesn't populates itself.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Product Offers</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: Products, optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: 'ID', value: ProductID, optionsCaption: '-'" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="if: ProductID">
                <select data-bind="options: ProductOffers, optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: 'ID', value: ProductOfferID, optionsCaption: '-'" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Product(id, name) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    function Offer(id, name) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    var viewModel = {
        Products: ko.observableArray(<%= LoadProducts() %>),

        ProductID: ko.observable('0'),
        ProductOfferID: ko.observable('0'),

        ProductOffers: ko.observable("")
    };

        viewModel.ProductID.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (typeof newValue != "undefined") {
                //alert("Selected product is : " + newValue);
                viewModel.ProductOffers = GetProductOffers(newValue);
                //alert(viewModel.ProductOffers);
            }
        });

        ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
            //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
            var result = ko.computed({
                read: target,  //always return the original observables value
                write: function (newValue) {
                    var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

                    //only write if it changed
                    if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                        target(valueToWrite);
                    } else {
                        //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                        if (newValue !== current) {
                            target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
            result(target());

            //return the new computed observable
            return result;
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        function GetProductOffers(ProductID) {

            alert("Fetching offers for Product : " + ProductID)

            var Val = "";
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testing.aspx/GetProductOffers",
                data: "{ProductID: '" + ProductID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    Val = msg.d;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        alert('Time out error.' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        alert('Ajax request aborted.' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else {
                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
            return Val;
        }
</script>
```

**EDIT : ** here is a what is hapening after tim's input.
[image: my problem]

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/neodescorpio/sPrVq/1/

**EDIT :**

here is the web method , i have changes it to produce a valid `JSON` acording to JSLint. Now the 2nd dropdown fills up but the problem is it's values never change whenever i change products, correct values are fetched but dropdown doesn't shows them.

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string GetProductOffers(long ProductID)
{
    StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();
    string json = "[{\"ID\": 0,\"Name\": \"Sorry ! No data found\"}]";
    bool first = true;

    List<DMS.ProductOfferDO> offers = ProductOffers.Get(ProductID);

    if (offers != null && offers.Count > 0)
    {
        sbScript.Append("[");
        foreach (var x in offers.OrderBy(d => d.IsCashOffer))
        {
            if (first)
            {
                sbScript.Append(string.Format("{{\"ID\": {0},\"Name\": \"{1}\"}}", x.ID, x.Name));
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                sbScript.Append(string.Format(",{{\"ID\": {0},\"Name\": \"{1}\"}}", x.ID, x.Name));
            }
        }
        sbScript.Append("]");
        json = sbScript.ToString();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your sample code that actually fetches any data or does anything to populate the second list on the first lists choice, so I think you either need to include more code or you are missing a large chunk of logic.

Comment: @TimHobbs thanks for immediate response , im not missing anything here as i said it works fine except for the problem. all that im trying to accomplish his get 2nd dropdown populated on change of first. and also get some details like price and stock. and show on the form.

Comment: My mistake - I think I brain farted and did not scroll down to see the rest. :)

Comment: it happens sometimes bro :D

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you declaring `ProductOffers` as `ko.observable("")`? It should be declared as an observable array instead: `ProductOffers: ko.observableArray([]);`

Also, in your JFiddle:

```
function GetProductOffers(ProductID) {
    var Val = "[new Offer(1,'Name'),new Offer(2,'Product A'),new Offer(4,'Product B'),new Offer(5,'Product C')]";               
    return Val;
}
```

Should be:

```
function GetProductOffers(ProductID) {
    var Val = [new Offer(1,'Name'),new Offer(2,'Product A'),new Offer(4,'Product B'),new Offer(5,'Product C')];             
    return Val;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sPrVq/2/

**EDIT:**

Try to modify your setup as follows:

```
  [WebMethod]
public static string GetProductOffers(long ProductID)
{   
    List<DMS.ProductOfferDO> offers = ProductOffers.Get(ProductID);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(offers);
}
```

You need to import: `using Newtonsoft.Json;` first of course.

And why did you use post? It should be a get:

```
function GetProductOffers(ProductID) {

         $.get("testing.aspx/GetProductOffers",
            { ProductID: ko.toJSON(ProductID) }
            )
            .done(function (data) {
                 viewModel.ProductOffers(JSON.parse(data));
            })
            .fail(function (data) { })
            .always(function () { });

}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
viewModel.ProductID.subscribe(function (newValue) {

    viewModel.ProductOffers.removeAll();

    if (newValue) {
        var productOffers = GetProductOffers(newValue);
        viewModel.ProductOffers(productOffers);
    }

});
```

Let us know how this goes please!

Comment: it works fine when i ive fixed values like in fiddle , but doesn't works when i use ajax web service , i used `JSON.parse` but it gives error SyntaxError: Unexpected token e

Comment: This has to do with your JSON result being invalid. Can you validate how it looks here? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: And by the way, this is used if your webservice returns a string. What does your method return?

Comment: This is returned and JSLint says it's invalid. [new Offer(6,'1 free unit')
,new Offer(7,'1 free unit')
,new Offer(5,'100 Per Unit')
]

Comment: This is not even JSON; you're returning a list then - you can't use JSON.parse :) 
Weird thing is, I hard-coded your returned value in the fiddle and it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/sPrVq/3/ looks like something is wrong with your webservice, can you check the console for any errors?

Comment: it is pretty much weird, web service results same result, infact i copied the data from web service from code behind while debuging.

Comment: Diana - hard coding that probably worked since the js was executed. It would probably work to wrap an `eval()` around the return result, but that would really just be a band aid fix. The key is to get Ali to fix the web method.

Comment: @TimHobbs agreed. But what do you think maybe wrong with the web method given that it does return correct results as he suggested?
Ali - please edit your question to include the web method code.

Comment: I think it isn't returning JSON - I think it is returning a string. But it is just a guess without seeing the code.

Comment: the values are shown now as i updated my web service, it's giving a valid JSON as i told earlier, now when i change the product selection it do populates offers dropdown , but when i again select another product is doesn't shows it's offers, it shows older offers of previously selected product, but when i select '-' from products and then select any product it then shows it's `productoffers`.

Answer (score 1):

`<td data-bind="with: ProductID">` is incorrect - this would only be necessary if you had a ProductID nested object. You don't so it is not needed. Just bind the second list to `ProductOffers` not `$data.ProductOffers`.

If what you are trying to achieve is to *not* show the second list until there are offers then just change `<td data-bind="with: ProductID">` to `<td data-bind="if: ProductOffers">` and that should work as expected.

**EDIT:**
I cannot say for sure as I don't know exactly what is returned, but my guess is there is a problem with `ProductOffers`. The ajax call returns the result and that is what you set `ProductOffers` to, but is the structure of each `ProductOffer` the same as what you have set for your select list binding? You have `Name` and `ID` as the bound values, are those properties of the items you return from your ajax call (`GetProductOffers`)?

**EDIT 2**
Ok, I see from your chat with Diana that your web method returns something like "[new Offer(..)...]". My guess is you have that method coded to simply return a string or something, right? You need to actually create a `List<Offer>` and then serialize that with something like `JavascriptSerializer` or JSON.net. You need to return JSON from the web method. It would be helpful if you showed the web method code, then we could help you figure out what is going wrong.

**EDIT 3**
I would definitely recomment *not* creating the JSON " by hand" - use either the built-in `JavascriptSerializer` or, better yet, use JSON.net. While it is not a must, it is cleaner and simpler. PLus, why re-invent the wheel, so to speak? Check [Diana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23588546/189937) out - she has besically outlined precisely what you need to do to get this to work. Good luck! :)

Comment: changed some code and something happened but now there is a long 2nd list showing nothing

Comment: Now it is showing one hundred empty options like `<option value=""></option>` , i don't know what's going on now

Comment: @Diana Nassar I have changed the `ProductOffer` to standard JSON and it's working fine now but now when i change the first dropdown's value 2nd dropdown dosen't updates itself. but the ajax request is getting the updated values, I can see them in alert.